# How to get title of screen in custom header component?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, react-navigation

Hope it's ok.

I Can't understand how custom header it's supposed to work.
I just want to send static properties to my Header depending on which route is selected.

I have:

```
export default AppNavigator = StackNavigator({
    Index:{
        screen: BottomNavigator,
    }
  },{
    navigationOptions: {
        header: AppHeader,
    },
    headerMode:'float',
  })
```

And my BottomNavigator is:

```
const BottomNavigator = TabNavigator({
    TabMenu1: { 
        screen: () => <Text> Resumé </Text>,
        navigationOptions: {
            title: 'Resumé'
        }
    },
    TabMenu2: {
        screen: () => <Text> Sells </Text>,
        navigationOptions: {
            title: 'Sells'
        }
    },
},{
    tabBarComponent: BottomNavigation
});
```

I'm expecting **{props.title}** in my custom header, is that right?

---

### **Additional info: My full route stack is:**

**AuthNavigator** have a wrapper that is connected to redux and have:

```
const AuthNavigator = StackNavigator({
  SignedIn: { 
    screen: MainNavigator
  }
 },{  
    headerMode:'none',
    initialRouteName: 'SignedIn'
  });
```

**MainNavigator:**

```
const MainNavigator = StackNavigator({
    Drawer: { 
        screen: DrawerNav
    },
  }, {  
    headerMode:'none',
  });
```

**DrawerNav:**

```
const DrawerNav = DrawerNavigator({
    Menu1: {
        screen: AppNavigator
    },
}, {
    contentComponent: DrawerNavigation,
    drawerWidth: 300
});
```

**AppNavigator** and **BottomNavigator** are described above

Answer (score 1):

for React Navigation 5 this works

```
props.scene.descriptor.options.title
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify title like this :

```
    RouteName:
    {
        screen: RouteScreen,
        navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
            title: navigation.state.params.title || 'StaticTitle'
        })
    }
```

Where navigation.state.params.title is the title you send as a params when you navigate (so if you want to add a variable for exemple). If you just want to use a static title, just use `title: 'StaticTitle'`

Comment: My navigation.state object in navigationOptions only have this properties:
**key** and **routeName**. 
 I'm using redux.
 btw, I think this navigationOptions isn't  coming to my Custom Header. I have to do something there or just use this.props.navigationOptions.title? In props of Custom Header i getting this: https://imgur.com/a/WTabi

Answer (score 0):

```
export const Navigator = StackNavigator(routes, {
  headerMode: 'screen',
  navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
    header: props => <Header {...props} />,
  }),
})
```

I did find a work around but it seems pretty verbose for what seems to be a common use case..

```
// Header.js
...
render() {
  const { getScreenDetails, scene } = this.props
  const details = getScreenDetails(scene)
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>{details.options.title}</Text>
    <View>
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

For React-Navigation v6, you can get the title prop (and other options) from the `options` prop: `props.options.title`.

This is useful because it also works when dynamically setting the header title using `navigation.setOptions({ title: 'new title' });`

Example usage:

```js
// in the navigator
<Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{header: (props) => <CustomHeaderComponent {...props} />}}>

// in your component
const CustomHeaderComponent = (props) => {
   const { title } = props.options;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**Resolved** with a code extracted of Header.js file of react-navigation:

The right way to get the title inside a custom header is:

```
const sceneOptions = props.getScreenDetails(props.scene).options;
const sceneTitle = sceneOptions.title;
```

Thanks all!

Comment: Could you provide the complete code? I get `props is not defined`.